# How to pass data between container view and main view controller properly

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I'm dealing with following problem: On main VC I have a TableView, and on container view controller I have a textField. I want to add every text, I'm typing in container automatically appears as a new row on tableView in main VC

By now I'm using segue to send data from main VC to container. But what should I implement to do the same in a reverse order? I though of implementing delegate of main VC in my container view, but I have no idea how to do that properly. Or maybe there is exist more common solution.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
class MessageViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentUser: User!

    var containerViewController: InputTextViewController?

    @IBOutlet weak var enterMessageView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!
}

extension MessageViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "moveToInputText" {
            let connectContainerViewController = segue.destination as? InputTextViewController
            containerViewController = connectContainerViewController

            containerViewController?.userSendMessageTo = currentUser

        }
    }
}

extension MessageViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentUser.mesaageHistory.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as! ChatMessageTableViewCell
        let data = currentUser.mesaageHistory[indexPath.row]
        cell.messageLabel.text = data.messageText

        return cell
    }
}

class InputTextViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!

    var userSendMessageTo: User!

    weak var delegate = MessageViewController()

    @IBAction func sendMessge(_ sender: Any) {

        handleSend()
        userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory.append(message)

        print(userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory[0].messageText)

        let row = userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory.count - 1
        let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(item: row, section: 0)

        print(userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory.count)

        delegate?.messageTableView.beginUpdates()
        delegate?.messageTableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        delegate?.messageTableView.endUpdates()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use the 'delegate' pattern properly

1. Protocol declaration & delegate member

   ```
   protocol InputTextViewControllerDelegate: class {
      func someFunc()

      func anotherFunc()
   }


   class InputTextViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: InputTextViewControllerDelegate?
   }
   ```
2. Protocol implementation & setting the delegate property

   ```
   extension MessageViewController, InputTextViewControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: InputTextViewControllerDelegate
    //

    func someFunc()
    {

    }


    func anotherFunc()
    {

    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "moveToInputText" {
       let connectContainerViewController = segue.destination as? InputTextViewController
       containerViewController = connectContainerViewController

       containerViewController

      }
     }
   }
   ```